# jQuery Mobile Linking to External Different Domain, and Then Back to App

Tags: jquery, iphone, mobile, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

I am designing an app in jQuery Mobile for an iPhone and have ran into an issue that I would like some help with.  Within the app, I have links to different external different domain sites example: (http://www.youtube.com, http://www.facebook.com).  The sites load fine from the link.  The issue is trying to return back to the app.  I have seen different other frameworks that will have a back option once you go the link and it returns back to the app.  I have researched and researched, and just haven't found a solution that I have seen.

I have also tried using iframes within the app just so I have an option to go back to another page in the app.  I cannot seem to get the iframes to function properly.  The ideal solution would be to be able to click the link, the page loads, it also creates a back button in the top left hand corner and once clicked it returns back to the app.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks,

Comment: Could you edit your question with some example code? http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

In your anchor tags just define the value "external" to the rel attribute.

```
<a href="www.google.com" rel="external">Go To Google</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response back.  I have tried that for several links including google and it takes me to the link fine, but I need to be able to get back to the app.  There is no options to close out or back.  Any other suggestions??